# Load specific .php with specific upstream server in nginx, php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Well I need suggestion, I have server setup one box - nginx, php-fpm and other box with only php-fpm installed, working as load balance. I am using `upstream` function to set load balance. How to serve specific .php file to work with only first server box- php-fpm? Don't allow to load with `load balance` server.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out by myself:
my vhost configuration:

```
 location ^~/download.php {
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
include fastcgi.conf;
 }

location ~ .*\.php?$ {
fastcgi_pass   phpupstream;
include fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
}
```